# Magento Product Image Links

Tags: php, magento

I have a question about a small problem I am having in Magento.

When you create a product you can upload multiple images into theat products gallery which show under the main image on the product view page.

My question is, is it possible to be able to add links to each of the images in the product backend just like you can add labels.

So when an extra image is clicked on the product view page it will take the user to a differnet page instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its possible, you have to create your own module on that.